# How do I access data from the Request header in the FireFox Console using JavaScript, jQuery or Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, token

```
var cities = [
  ['123456789', 'City1']
]

var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + token + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
var token = keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;



$.ajax({
  url: 'http://webserver/userportal/api/rest/content/archives/-1/page?ownerPublic=2&page=0&pageSize=10&isTrash=false&durationVal=0&durationOpt=-1',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.plcm.plcm-content-archive+json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer anonymous',
    token: '3a90f457e9774382bd8202af85f1b4741510863389858', // i hard coded this because I can't figure out how to get it from the Request header
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    Pragma: 'no-cache'
  }
})
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
    $("div.displayname div").each(function (index) {
      var title = $(this).attr('title')
      var titleDate = ''


      vicenages.forEach(function (vicenage) {
        if (title.indexOf(vicenage[0]) > -1) {
          var datePart = title.split('_')[2]
          var year = datePart.substr(0, 4)
          var month = datePart.substr(4, 2)
          var day = datePart.substr(6, 2)
          var dayString = month + '-' + day + '-' + year

          var newFileName = vicenage[1] + ' ' + dayString

          $.ajax({
            url: '/url',
            method: 'PUT'
          })

          console.log(title, newFileName)
        }
      })
    })

  })
```

I am having trouble getting the token from the request header. I am running my code within the FireFox Developer Console ONLY.

I am trying to access these items

```
Host
User-Agent
Accept
Accept-Language
Cache-Control
If-Modified-Since
token
Authorization
Referer
Cookie
Connection
```

Comment: `success ()` method on ajax

Comment: which request headers ?

Comment: In The Developer Console, I see it says "Request Header" on the Side Bar. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie